Is this a Riemann sum?
I have come a cross with a sum that looks like this:
$$\sum_{x\in{\Lambda_N}}\epsilon^2 k(\epsilon x)e^{-i\pi\omega \cdot \epsilon^2 x}\quad \quad\quad\quad(*)$$
Here $x$ takes values in the discrete two dimensional torus: $\Lambda_N$=$\{-N,-N+1,\dots,N\}^2\subseteq \mathbb{Z}^2,$ $k:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ is a test function that is smooth and compactly supported, $w\in\{-N,-N+1,\dots,N\}^2$ denotes Fourier modes, $\epsilon=\frac{2}{2N+1}$ is a small parameter that goes to $0$.
My question is, is it possible to obtain $(*)$ as a Riemann sum that converges to some integral, as $\epsilon\to0(N\to\infty)?$
I was thinking to rewrite this sum as
$$\sum_{x\in{\Lambda_\epsilon}}\epsilon^2 k(x)e^{-i\pi\epsilon \omega \cdot x},$$
where $\Lambda_\epsilon=\epsilon\Lambda_N=\{\frac{-2N}{2N+1},\frac{-2N+2}{2N+1},\dots,\frac{2N}{2N+1}\}^2\subseteq [-1,1)^2.$ So that as $\epsilon\to0(N\to\infty),$ the mesh size goes to 0, and this sum is nearly in the form of a Riemann sum.
However, in the exponential $e^{-i\pi\epsilon\omega \cdot x}$ we still have $\epsilon $ in the exponent, which will bring $e^{-i\pi\epsilon\omega \cdot x}\to 1$ as $\epsilon\to 0.$
Is there anyway to write the sum as $\int_{[-1,1)^2}k(x)e^{-i\pi\epsilon\omega \cdot x}dx$ as $\epsilon\to 0,$ or is it impossible at all? Many thanks for any suggestions and help!

As for real $t$ there holds $|e^{it}-1|\le |t|$ we get $$\left |e^{i\pi \omega \cdot \epsilon^2x}-1\right |\le \epsilon\pi|\omega\cdot \epsilon x|$$ Therefore
$$\left |\sum_{x\in\Delta_N}\epsilon^2 k(\epsilon x)e^{i\pi \omega \cdot \epsilon^2x}-\sum_{x\in\Delta_N}\epsilon^2 k(\epsilon x)\right |\\  \le \epsilon^3\pi \sum_{x\in\Delta_N}|k(\epsilon x)||\omega\cdot \epsilon x|\\ \le \epsilon^3\pi(2N+1)^2\max_{t\in[-1,1]^2} |k(t)||\omega\cdot t|\underset{N}{\to} 0$$Furthermore $$\sum_{x\in\Delta_N}\epsilon^2 k(\epsilon x) \to \iint \limits_{[-1,1]^2}k(x)\,dx$$

Thank you so much for your answer! I think the bounding method makes sense and it helps a lot!
